# Atom.io search and delete, is it possible?

Tags: atom-editor

Has anyone figured out a way to use Atom.io's awesome search feature to find and delete lines? For example, I want to remove all lines that match `^\s*color: #3f3f3f;$`from my css.

I don't want to leave empty lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `$` doesn't match newline or carriage return I needed to be more explicit. The pattern `\n?\r?` seemed to do the trick for me.

My final regex is:

`^\s*color: #3f3f3f;\n?\r?`

It might need to be modified depending on your line endings. I think `^\s*color: #3f3f3f;\n?\r?\n?` should be pretty universal.

Comment: For some reason works only in a file, not across a path...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace that match with an empty string - ie, leave the `Replace in current buffer` field empty, and do a `Replace`.

You have to take care of matching the whole line so you don't end up with an empty line.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it and if you simply leave the replace field empty, then click replace, it will delete.

Comment: With the regex I provided it leaves an empty line as @mgarciaisaia suggested.